# mmap regions allocating from reserved stack space?

Tags: linux, malloc, heap-memory, stack-overflow, mmap

In our product we use a `malloc` implementation that relies exclusively on mmap for memory allocation.  We also do a fair use of `alloca`ing.  We've just encountered a problem where mmap will allocate regions that *should* be reserved to stack space (thus causing very bad things to happen when one of our larger alloca's spills into the malloc'd region).

The limitation of our process' allocation is our VM address space, not physical memory. We've watched the /proc/*/maps file as the process runs and watched malloc eat up any available address space. It eventually resorts to allocating addresses within the stacks rlimit-set range, and eventually a large `alloca` stretches into it.

We've tried to work around it by `alloca`ing our entire stack limit at startup, but that hasn't proved stable across platforms (it segfaults trying to access the `alloca`d memory  on my 2.4 dev box, while it works on the 2.6 production machine).

Is there any way to actually reserve the address space?  What else can be done?

Comment: Using mmap() for malloc() is really bad idea. Abusing alloca() is even worse... First time I hear that somebody has exhausted the virtual memory space. Or we're talking about 32bit here?

Comment: At least two widely used malloc implementations (phkmalloc and jemalloc) use anonymous mmap.  The one we use (jemalloc) is the malloc library for recent releases of stdlib.  Someone must think it's a good idea.

Yes, 32bit using PME with a half-n-half kernel userspace split. Furthermore we're mapping about a gig of memory from the kernel into userspace, so our available address range is only about a gig out of the gate.

Comment: @Dummy00001: I've read that OpenBSD malloc() mmap()s everything >= pagesize. dlmalloc() (used on glibc and uClibc among others) has a MMAP_THRESHOLD, which I think is usually somewhere around 128Kb.

Comment: @ninjal: OpenBSD: yes, they have activated that specifically after tuning kernel to support the creation of new mapping at acceptable speed. Otherwise, more mappings process has, more time context switch requires. Even OpenBSD can't avoid that. And the mmap()ing of large memory blocks has different meaning: unlike heap, one can return the memory back to OS using munmap().

Comment: you can return heap memory allocated via sbrk to the OS too (via brk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently an recently documented security vulnerability used in a privilege escalation exploit.  Allegedly newer kernel versions will be patched.

http://www.exploit-db.com/download_pdf/14696/

Answer (score 0):

Old versions of heartbeat ensured stack space was commited by calling a recursive function that memset()ed 1Kb at a time to 0xff. Heartbeat did this to be able to mlock() all memory it could potentially need.

Comment: Ideally I could somehow reserve the addresses without forcing them to be backed by memory, but as it stands I think something like this is the only way it can work.